# Wordpress, проблема с весом и размером товара

Tags: wordpress

Сайт на Wordpress.
В настройках Woocommerce стоят: вес в г (граммах), габариты в см. (фото 1)
[image: woo]

но при добавлении нового товара все эти величины идут на англ языке (фото 2)
[image: tovar]
Решение проблемы на фото 2 - отсюда: `https://qna.habr.com/q/374588` . Ввиду того, что тема старая и видимо файлы системы изменились, то данный кусок кода про вес в админке был найден по такому пути: `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-product-data-shipping.php` 
в данной строке: `'label'       => __( 'Weight', 'woocommerce' ) . ' (' . get_option( 'woocommerce_weight_unit' ) . ')',` изменил на такую: `'label'       => __( 'Weight', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ' . __(esc_attr( get_option( 'woocommerce_weight_unit' ) ), 'woocommerce'),` - теперь при добавлении товара в админке появилась русская буква (г)

Но на самом сайте осталось тоже самое - англ язык (фото 3)
[image: товарсайт]
Теперь скорее всего надо изменить этот файл, чтобы решить проблему отображения на сайте:

```
/wp-content/themes/моя_тема/woocommerce/single-product/product-attributes.php
```

Состоит из таких строк:

```js
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

if ( ! $product_attributes ) {
 return;
}
?>
<table class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">
 <?php foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute_key => $product_attribute ) : ?>
  <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--<?php echo esc_attr( $product_attribute_key ); ?>">
   <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['label'] ); ?></th>
   <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['value'] ); ?></td>
  </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Никакой проблемы нет, все верно, любая доставка будет измеряться в граммах, а не кг, тоннах.

Comment: Я говорю про язык в самой системе (русский) и про габариты (которые почему то сами изменяются на англ буквы)

Comment: ./wp-content/languages/plugins/woocommerce-admin-ru_RU.po - отвечает за русский язык в админке
./wp-content/languages/plugins/woocommerce-ru_RU.po - за русский язык во фронтэнде

Если измените файлы *.po, то нужно будет скомпилировать с теми же именами, но расширением ".mo" - они-то и используются на сайте. Сделать это можно например с помощью программы Poedit/

Comment: #: includes/admin/settings/class-wc-settings-products.php:340
msgid "g"
msgstr "г"

вот что нашлось в файле woocommerce-ru_RU.po

найдя указанный пхп - там тоже все англ буквами..

Comment: Всё правильно. В файле *.po сказано, что в таком-то файле .php на строке 340 есть значение "g", а фраза msgid "g" msgstr "г" говорит, что "g" надо на лету заменить на "г", если русский файл подключен. Ну или на другие значения для других языков. Важно другое. Наряду с файлами *.po  есть ли файлы *.mo с теми же названиями? Именно они используются для переводов.

Comment: Конвертировал файл woocommerce-ru_RU.mo (взят оттуда же где .po) и в нем нашел строчки
msgid "g"
msgstr "г"
то есть все норм как бы? Но ничего не поменять и ничего не меняется на сайте..

Comment: Порылся в файлах, нашел такой: /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-product-data-shipping.php
В нем есть такой кусок: 'label'       => __( 'Weight', 'woocommerce' ) . ' (' . get_option( 'woocommerce_weight_unit' ) . ')',
При создании нового товара раздел Вес в html выглядит так: <label for="_weight">Вес (g)</label> (тут как раз эта g, которую надо заменить на г )
Может это чем то поможет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный код вставляем в functions.php нашей темы (меня интересовала конкретно величина в граммах):

```
function localize_weight_units($weight) {
    return str_replace('g', 'г', $weight);
}
add_filter('woocommerce_format_weight', 'localize_weight_units');
```

Comment: Тогда уже лучше return 'г';